# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I had uploaded my application in IIS server(is working fine on local), and got the below error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
```

my web.config looks like

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
```

my packages.config looks like

```
 <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

and when I check the version of my dll, it shows the same i.e 4.1.0, I don't know why I am getting the above error

Comment: Your project could be using a library which depends on Microsoft.Owin v2.1.0.0. EDIT oh wait, I have just seen that you posted an irrelevant assemblyIdentity from web.config. See if there is one with name="Microsoft.Owin" in there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File Explorer` navigate to the project `bin` folder. Delete all files in `bin` folder and then try `Rebuilding` the whole `solution`